# Are there any notable artists out there that use an emoji in their name?

Tags: names

I know there are artists that use non-letter characters (probably the dollar sign $ is the most notably). But are the artist the use emojis as part of their names?

Comment: How are you defining ‘emoji’?  For example, does [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician))'s [love symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Symbol) count?  It would seem to fit both [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) and [Wiktionary's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emoji) definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only find one.

Four Tet (Kieran Hebden) used ⣎⡇ꉺლ༽இ•̛)ྀ◞ ༎ຶ ༽ৣৢ؞ৢ؞ؖ ꉺლ as an alias.

> Don't ask us how to pronounce Four Tet's side project, ⣎⡇ꉺლ༽இ•̛)ྀ◞ ༎ຶ ༽ৣৢ؞ৢ؞ؖ ꉺლ. More experimental in nature than his main project, the seemingly random string of symbols side project has song names that are just as strange. Luckily for fans of this entry, it's rather easy to just google "Four Tet's side project" and copy and paste the name into Spotify.

> [image]

Source: [The 6 Most Obscure Artist Names in Electronic Music - EDM.com - The Latest Electronic Dance Music News, Reviews & Artists](https://edm.com/features/most-bizarre-artist-names)

Comment: But are any of those characters emojis?